# jquery ui autocomplete focus on element event via keyboard clears input content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, autocomplete

i have a text box  with jquery ui autocomplete initialized with it, and few more. what i am doing is focusing on the next text box when enter key is pressed.

now whenever i focus on autocomplete text box via enter press, existing text gets cleared. it only happens when focus is triggered via enter key, not on tab or shift tab.

i already tried initializing with

```
focus: function( event, ui ) {
            event.preventDefault(); 
        }
```

bit still the problem persists.

how do i prevent textbox from clearing its content ?

Comment: Do you know whether the value of the autocomplete input is still there in that focus method?

Comment: i tried alerting the value in focus event, it does not alert when focused.

Comment: So it gets emptied before the focus event